# JQuery Add Fade Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a background image changer using JQuery, I have succeeded thus far, however I am unsure on how or where to add a .fadeIn() effect in my code:

```
$(function() {
  var body = $('.div-slideshow');
  var backgrounds = [
    'url(img/homeImg.jpg)',
    'url(img/homeImg2.jpg)',
    'url(img/homeImg3.jpg)'
  ];
  var current = 0;

  function nextBackground() {
    body.css(
      'background',
      backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
  }
  setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
  body.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done with `.fadeIn()` since you are using the same element and only changing its background.

Add this CSS3 transition to your `.div-slideshow` class

```
.div-slideshow {
  transition: background 1s linear;
}
```

You can change the transition time if you want.

That way the backgrounds will transition automatically when changing the url property.